# Getting 'ngbCollapse' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. error after moving components into sub module

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-module

Error

> compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'ngbCollapse' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("][ngbCollapse]="isHidden">

I have a NavbarComponent and a FooterComponent that I want to move into the SharedModule, to keep the root app.module cleaner.

**app.module**

```
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
// import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
// import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

// Modules
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    PasswordResetComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    // NavbarComponent,
    // FooterComponent,
```

**share.module**

However, once I moved those components into here, and update their paths correctly `./` -> `../` the app breaks.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { NavbarComponent } from '../navbar/navbar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from '../footer/footer.component';
import { TermsComponent } from './terms.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './not-found.component';
import { PrivacyPolicyComponent } from './privacy-policy.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    TermsComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    PrivacyPolicyComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  isHidden = true;
  oauthUrl = this.authService.generateOauthUrl();

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  logout() {
    sessionStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

Then a couple of lines with the `[ngbCollapse]` in **navbar.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn()" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" [ngbCollapse]="isHidden">
```

I think this has something to do with the relative paths, any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `ng-bootstrap`? If so, add `NgbModule` to the imports section of the `SharedModule`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Ah thanks! Yeah that was it :) now I'm getting a different error `'app-navbar' is not a known element:` but that is a different question, care to post the full answer? I did forget to import that in the new shared.module.

Comment: For the second error, you probably need to add the shared components (e.g. `NavbarComponent`) to the `exports` of the `SharedModule`, and to import the `SharedModule` in the module where the components are actually used.

Comment: Hmm I am importing the `NavbarComponent` and I'm exporting the `SharedModule` in the code above, or is there another place I missed?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To use `ng-bootstrap` components and directives in Angular templates, you need to import the `NgbModule`. In your case, you should import it in the `SharedModule`. Also, in order to use the shared components in other parts of the application, you should export them from the `SharedModule` and import the `SharedModule` in the modules when the components are to be used.

**shared.module.ts**

```
...
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    TermsComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    PrivacyPolicyComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    TermsComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    PrivacyPolicyComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

Note: if you want to use `ng-bootstrap` components and directives in templates outside of the `SharedModule`, you should add `NgbModule` to the `exports` of the `SharedModule`.

Comment: AH gotcha :) about the exports array

Answer (score 1):

To work with ng-bootsrap you should add this dependency first :

> ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

source: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

then imporst the module as follows :

```
   import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        NgbModule
      ],
...
```